# How to keep the current Accordion active on page refresh in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have following code of Accordion. The code is working fine. I want to keep the selected tab active on page refresh. But the javascript I have added is not working. I am not getting as to what is the exact problem.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('data-target'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#accordionExample button[data-target="' + activeTab + '"]').collapse('show');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you add the id (which div you want to show) into session.
Then after reload you just get the session. and show the current div by js. Here is my code to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get saved data from sessionStorage
  let selectedCollapse = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedCollapse');
  if(selectedCollapse != null) {
    $('.accordion .collapse').removeClass('show');
    $(selectedCollapse).addClass('show');
  }
  //To set, which one will be opened
  $('.accordion .btn-link').on('click', function(){ 
    let target = $(this).data('target');
    //Save data to sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedCollapse', target);
  });
});
```

> Note that, Based on your code I think you used bootstrap and jquery. You must need the jquery at least to perform the above actions.

I don't know if this is the right way or not, but it will work somehow.

Comment: Actually thank goes to you. 
I didnt do that before. For your question, I learnt how to use this. :) . btw welcome you.
here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/hasanali05/s6w7uezn/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple method:

```
$("#").load(location.href + " #");
```

Always give space just before the second `#` sign, otherwise the above code will return the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post particularly helpful when solving my own Bootstrap Accordion problem where AJAX is not an option. I do, however, want to expand the code a little that hasan05 provided. I basically added checks to see if the user navigated away from the page completely, or just reloaded it (say a postback operation for instance). I set mine to destroy session data after 3 seconds. It is generally good practice to destroy your sessionStorage if you are no longer using them.

```
//:: Accordion check: Saves current accordion tab state in a session, so it can be returned to on page reload
function setAccordionSession() {
    let selectedAccordion = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedAccordion');

    //:: if sessionStorage has a value, choose that header to expand
    if (selectedAccordion != null) {
        $('.accordion .collapse').removeClass('show');
        $('.accordion-button').attr('aria-expanded', false);
        $('.accordion-button').addClass('collapsed');

        $(selectedAccordion).addClass('show');
        $(selectedAccordion).attr('aria-expanded', true);

        //:: Loop through each Accordion Button to see if data-bs-target exists and remove collapsed class 
        $.each($('.accordion-button'), function () {
            if ($(this).is('[data-bs-target="' + selectedAccordion + '"]')) {
                $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
            }
        });
    }
    //:: no sessionStorage value present, therefore we must want the default accordion views
    else {            
        $('div#collapseOne').addClass('show');
        $('h2#headingOne > button').attr('aria-expanded', true);
        $('h2#headingOne > button').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
};

//:: When one clicks the accordion button/tab, save its current data-bs-target value to sessionStorage
$('.accordion .accordion-button').on('click', function () {
    let target = $(this).data('bs-target');
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedAccordion', target);        
});

//:: When User navigates away from page, take a stamp of current Date/Time
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    window.localStorage.unloadTime = JSON.stringify(new Date());        
})
//:: Check unload time vs load time to determine if sessions should be cleared or not.
window.onload = function () {
    let loadTime = new Date();
    let unloadTime = new Date(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.unloadTime));
    let refreshTime = loadTime.getTime() - unloadTime.getTime();        

    //:: If user was gone more than 3 seconds, clear the sessionStorage and generate accordions with defaults
    if (refreshTime > 3000) {            
        sessionStorage.clear();
        setAccordionSession();
    }
    else {
        //:: Page must have been refreshed, maintain current state using existing sessionStorage
        setAccordionSession();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for solution in react, they can use it like that:

```js
const accordionLocalStorageKey = 'cachedAccordionKey'

const getLastActiveKeyOfAccordionOnLinksPage = () => localStorage.getItem(accordionLocalStorageKey)
const setLastActiveKeyOfAccordionOnLinksPage = (value) => localStorage.setItem(accordionLocalStorageKey, value)

const LearnAccordion = () => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(getLastActiveKeyOfAccordionOnLinksPage)
  const handleSelect = (value) => {
    setLastActiveKeyOfAccordionOnLinksPage(value)
    setActiveKey(value)
  }
  return <div>
    <Accordion activeKey={activeKey} onSelect={handleSelect}>
      <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
        <Accordion.Header id={"accordionHeader"}>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
        <Accordion.Body>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </Accordion.Body>
      </Accordion.Item>
    </Accordion>
  </div>
}
```