# Keep accordion open after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an sidenav with accordion menus, but when I refresh or go to another page it closes. How can it be stay open after these actions? Example here with CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/ag9q1tvc/

JavaScript:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      parent.style.maxHeight = parseInt(parent.style.maxHeight) + panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class='sidenav'>
  <button class='accordion'><i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp; FAV</button>
  <button class='accordion'><i class='fa fa-th-large' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp; SALES</button>
  <div class='panel'>
      <a href='item1.php'>&emsp;ITEM 1</a>
       <a href='item2.php'>&emsp;ITEM 2</a>
</div>
```

I couldn't find the exact method for my problem in other answers.
Thank you!

Comment: You probably only want it to stay open, after it has been clicked once? So when the user visits the page the first time it should be closed?

Comment: it should stay open until it closed

Comment: Create a session and store the state of the accordion in the session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep the current Accordion active on page refresh in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618288/how-to-keep-the-current-accordion-active-on-page-refresh-in-bootstrap)

Comment: The answer you accepted was deleted, did someone else answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store accordion state somewhere, it can be sessionStorage or localStorage also called cookies. As for me sessionStorage is the best way of doing that, here is an example of what you can do:

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      sessionStorage.setItem(parent.id, ""); // store it as closed
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      parent.style.maxHeight = parseInt(parent.style.maxHeight) + panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      sessionStorage.setItem(parent.id, "open"); // store it as open
    }
  });

  // here we are getting state from sessionStorage
  var parent = acc[i].parentElement;
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(parent.id) === "open") {
    parent.querySelector(".panel").style.maxHeight = parent.querySelector(".panel").scrollHeight + "px";
    parent.style.maxHeight = parseInt(parent.style.maxHeight) + parent.querySelector(".panel").scrollHeight + "px";
    acc[i].classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

Note that it will store state until browser is closed, otherwise you can use cookies.

Comment: looks good. actually i have more than one accordion buttons, and this code marks all of them as 'open'. Is it possible just to keep the clicked one open?

Comment: like this. https://jsfiddle.net/ag9q1tvc/1/ if you open one then hit run again both opens

Comment: @i_dont_know_anything_YET Yep, it's possible. You can assign unique identifier for each section in your HTML and store them separately. Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crk7x1jw/)

Comment: very good! works really well! i have a transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; so it has a little animation as it opens. is it possible to actually stay open? as i see its reopening the things.

Comment: @i_dont_know_anything_YET You can set `style.transition = "unset";` to element before setting active class in getting state part. With that modification animation will be not applied if sessionStorage state is open.

Answer (score 1):

## :target Selector and anchor tag (no JS)

The :target selector matches if the id of an element is equal to the hash (#) after the url. Since the browser keeps the hash with reload or navigation, this will persist the state of the accordion in the url.

- PRO: No JavaScript needed, cross-browser compatible
- CON: If you need the # for something else (like single page routing) this is not an option.

```css
#accordion {
  display: blocK;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#accordion > .content {
  display: none;
}

#accordion:target > .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#accordion">open</a>
<a href="#">close</a>

<a id="accordion">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use local storage, it is a variable that is store in the cache of the browser

```
localStorage.setItem("item1", "active");
```

You can see more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).